# McLaurin expansions help

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

The problem:
Study the convergence/divergence of this limit, as $a \in \mathbb{R}$ changes

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^a \biggl( \frac{1}{\log(2x+\sqrt{1+x^3})} -\frac{1}{\log(2x+1)} \biggr)$$

I did that:
$\sqrt{1+x^3}=1+\frac{x^3}{2} + o(x^3)$ so

$\log\left(1 +2x +\frac{x^3}{2} + o(x^3) \right) = 2x - \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{x^3}{2} +o(x^3)$

and $\log\left(1 +2x \right) = 2x - \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{8x^3}{3} +o(x^3)$ .

Now how can I expand $\frac{1}{ 2x - \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{x^3}{2} +o(x^3)}$ and $\frac{1}{ 2x - \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{8x^3}{3} +o(x^3)}$ ?
I don't find on internet some expansion for these fractions(!)

Comment: The $x^2/2$ term should be replaced by $2x^2$ and further $\log(1+2x+x^3/2+o(x^3))=2x-2x^2+19x^3/6+o(x^3)$

Comment: The last two expressions are erroneous. But if they were correct, there is no need to expand them.  Let them be $1/A$ and $1/B.$ Then $1/A-1/B=(B-A)/AB,$ with $B-A=(8/3-1/2)x^3+o(x^3)$ and $AB=4x^2+o(x^2).$

Answer (score 2):

Make them into one fraction.

$\frac {\ln (1+ 2x) - \ln (2x + \sqrt{1+x^3})}{\ln (1+ 2x) \ln (2x + \sqrt{1+x^3})}$

Expand the series for $\sqrt {1+x^3} = 1 + \frac 12 x^3 - \frac 18 x^6 \cdots$

$\frac {\ln (1+ 2x) - \ln ( 1 + 2x + \frac 12x^3\cdots)}{\ln (1+ 2x) \ln (1+2x + \frac 12 x^3 \cdots )}$

and then the logs.

$\ln(1+2x) = 2x - \frac 12 (2x)^2 + \frac 13 (2x)^3 \cdots\\
\ln(1+2x+\frac 12 x^3) = 2x  + \frac 12 x^3 - \frac 12 (2x + \frac 12x^3)^2 \cdots $

the difference $\frac 12 x^3 - x^4\cdots$

The product $4x^2 - 8x^3 \cdots$

So it would appear that the numerator is of order $x^{a+3}$ and the denominator is of order $x^2$

The limit coverges to 0 if $x > -1$ and diverges if $a < -1$ and converges to $-\frac 18$ if $a = -1$

Comment: Glad that you crossed $32k$ reputation points due to a vote of mine. Keep up the good work! As for me- at the moment of the vote I have $666$ reputation points. A long trip to get there!

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the reciprocals like $1/(2x-2x^2+8x^3/3+o(x^3))$ using binomial theorem as $$(1/2x)(1-x+4x^2/3+o(x^2))^{-1}=\frac{1}{2x}\left(1+x-x^2/3+o(x^2)\right)$$ which is the same as $(1/2x)+(1/2)-x/6+o(x)$. Similarly the other expression is $(1/2x)+(1/2)-7x/24+o(x) $ and thus the given expression is equal to $-x^{a+1}/8+o(x^{a+1})$ and you can now conclude.